# currency selector updating in local.xml

Tags: magento

I want to keep the currency selector in top. So i added this code in local.xml:

```
 <default>
     <reference name="header">
          <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" before="catalog.leftnav" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
     </reference>
 </default>
```

Now how can i remove currency selector from **left**, **right** position. I tried this:

```
<default>   
     <reference name="left">
         <remove name="currency"/>
     </reference>
</default>
```

It removes all currency selector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your header block currency as well. I would try renaming that header block (try `header.currency`) and see if that does it for you.

Comment: Ya! I got solution renaming the header.currency. Here is my code: `<reference name="left">
            <remove name="currency"/>
        </reference>`

Answer (score 1):

To remove from search results left side bar I used this:

Commet this out from `directory.xml`

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" before="-" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<remove name="currency"/>
```

Removes curreny module.If you want to remove currency from left sidebar and use it somewhere,code must be

```
<default>   
     <reference name="left">
         <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
     </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Not removing from left position.

Comment: I have a question. Please could you explain! This is working `<reference name="left">
            <remove name="currency"/>
        </reference>` But it's not working `<reference name="left">
         <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
     </reference>`